# Assigning multiple table variables of different types

Tags: matlab, time-series, variable-assignment

Have a time series of data with missing time stamps. Have to find them and insert rows with the missing time stamps.
As I'm working with a `table` I would like to assign both `string`and `double` values in one step from one table to another.

For example:

```
% initialise data
n = rand(2,1);
tst = cellstr('ts1');
tst(2,1) = cellstr('ts2');
aTable = table(ts,n)

% create 2nd table for assignment
[x y] = size(aTable)
aTable2 = array2table(zeros(x, y));

% attempt assignment
aTable2(1,:) = aTable(2,:);
```

Throws out:

> "Error using table/subsasgnDot (line 234)
>
> Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
>
> Error in table/subsasgn (line 66)
>
> ```
>    t = subsasgnDot(t,s,b);"
> ```

Have tried several assignment methods, for instance using `VariableNames`, but to no avail. Surely I'm not the first to want to be able to assign multiple `Variables` in vectorized form - grateful for any pointers and solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Simply do not assign types of the columns yet. You have declared the columns to be doubles by calling array2table. The solution is to just create a table without rows or columns and let the type of each column be determined upon assignment:

```
clear all
clc;

% initialise data
n = rand(2,1);
tst = cellstr('ts1');
tst(2,1) = cellstr('ts2');
aTable = table(tst,n);

% create 2nd table for assignment, having neither rows nor columns.
aTable2 = table; % <--- The trick

% Assign whatever you like
aTable2(1,:) = aTable(2,:);
```

Comment: excellent, thanks! simple and elegant, even if probably not the most efficient computationally since it commits the Matlab cardinal sin of growing an array. the solution isn't obvious for that same reason - Matlab pre-programs users to pre-allocate arrays.

Comment: Well assigning the first row is not growing it really, it's more like initializing it, just like you do with array2table. Of course you shouldn't be appending other rows one by one.